# Appending the result of a partial to a list

Tags: python

I am trying to build a list of dictionaries.

```
from functools import partial

def build_list():
    lst = []
    lst.append(join_function({
        'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}
    }))
    return lst

def join_function(query):
    return partial(special_join_fn, kind='Case')

def special_join_fn(query, kind):
    return {
        'must': [query, {'term': {'findings.kind': kind}}]
    }
```

When I call `build_list()` I expect the return value to be:

```
[
    {'must': [
        {'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}}, 
        {'term': {'findings.kind': 'Case'}}
    ]}
]
```

but all I am getting back is

```
[<functools.partial object at 0x7fa60be63260>]
```

Why is this happening? Am I using partials wrongly?

Comment: Why are you using `functools.partial` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: `functools.partial` gives you back a callable (a function you can call), but you're not calling it.

```
def build_list():
    lst = []
    lst.append(join_function({
        'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}
    })())
    return lst
```

(the difference here is the extra `()` after calling `join_function`, so as to call the function it returned).

Also, you need to pass `query` through:

```
def join_function(query):
    return partial(special_join_fn, query, kind='Case')
```

I tacked on a main test-runner using `pprint.pprint`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(build_list())

$ python bard.py
[{'must': [{'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}},
           {'term': {'findings.kind': 'Case'}}]}]
```

(I'm assuming you're mostly just experimenting with `partial` here since for this use case it's just obscuring things.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using them wrongly; I don't get why you are using them at all in your example code.

Partially applied functions are like this:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

add3 = partial(add, a=3)

print add3(b=4)
```

In my example, `add3` is partially applied - it's preset `a=3` and is waiting to be called again with just a `b` value.

So your code:

```
def build_list():
    lst = []

# here you call join_function with one parameter. join_function returns a partially 
# applied function, which you never call.

    lst.append(join_function({
        'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}
    }))
    return lst


# here, join_function takes a 'query' parameter, which you throw away 
# and don't use, so what you sent in is lost.

def join_function(query):
    return partial(special_join_fn, kind='Case')

# here, the query is missing so it can't be put in
def special_join_fn(query, kind):
    return {
        'must': [query, {'term': {'findings.kind': kind}}]
    }
```

After that, back at the `build_list` you have a function with `kind` specified, waiting for a `query`, because your `query` parameter went nowhere. You never call the function you get back, you just add it straight to the list.

Here is a reworked version which does work:

```
from functools import partial

def build_list():
    lst = []
    f = join_function()

    query = {
        'terms': {'field_name': ['a', 'b']}
    }

    lst.append(f(query))
    return lst

def join_function():
    return partial(special_join_fn, kind='Case')

def special_join_fn(query, kind):
    return {
        'must': [query, {'term': {'findings.kind': kind}}]
    }

print build_list()
```

Although it seems a convoluted way to do what it does.